# will two entangled particles still remain entangled if one of the pair if sent inside of a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, quantum-entanglement

Imagine that i had two entangled photons . I kept a photon beside me without knowing its spin and sent the other photon inside a black hole . Then i measure the spin of the photon beside me . Is is certain that the photon inside the black hole will have opposite spin as the one beside me?

Comment: Hah! Maybe we will figure it out when one would actually come up with a decent explanation of why black holes even exist and what they are. But it is a cool idea to try to monitor a member of an entangled pair of electrons while the other one is in a black hole; hence, use it as a probe... Me like it =P

Comment: My suggestion would be to specify which model of a black hole you would like to consider, if you expect more exact answer.

Comment: From your position the second photon will not reach the event horizon at any time in your future.  So there is never a time, in your reference frame, when it's inside.

Comment: @StephenG But when black holes grow the event horizon grows with it, right?